# Clone animated attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have recently changed my drag and drop game to make it easier for young users.

Basically instead of dragging and dropping letters to spell words you now click the letter and it animates into the correct area automatically.

My problem is when I had the drag and drop function the letters would clone so you could use each one more than once in a game. Now they don't.

Is there a different way of doing that outside the drag and drop event?

```
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target     = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
var targetPos  = target.position();
var currentPos = $(this).offset();
var b = $(this);

if(target.length) {


    if(b.attr("data-letter") == target.attr("data-letter")){
        $(this).addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');
            $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('wordglow');
            $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);
    }


        b.remove().appendTo('table').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : currentPos.top,
        'left': currentPos.left
        });
        {
        b.animate({
           top  : targetPos.top,
            left : targetPos.left
        }, 'slow', function() {
            b.remove().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(target);
            target.addClass('occupied');
        });
      }
   }
});
```

This is what I used in the drag and drop function...

```
    $('.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element and [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the clone:

```
if (target.length) {
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
        b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow"
    ).appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        target.addClass("occupied");
    });
}
```

(As a side note, you do not have to call `remove()` before `appendTo()`, as the element will be moved if it already has a parent.)

Comment: When they clone they take the css from the ones that go to the grid how can I stop this. This fiddle will show you what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/8/ @Frédéric Hamidi

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you probably have to add the `wordglow` and `workglow3` classes to the clone instead of the original element.

Comment: How would i differentiate the two styles though in that part of the code? @Frédéric Hamidi

Comment: Well, as probably by comparing the `data-letter` attributes as you're doing right now :) I'll try to integrate that part in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually clone your element using the following:

$(e.target).clone().after(e.target);

Comment: Where in the function would you put that? @phunder

Comment: You add it when you start dragging the original element.